# With boost::json, Is it possible to declare two separate value_from conversions in different namespaces?

Tags: c++, json, boost

Lets say I have a class `Customer` in namespace `Data`. Using [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/json/doc/html/json/dom/conversion.html), I know I can convert this into valid JSON by declaring a function with the signature: `void tag_invoke( const value_from_tag&, value& jv, Customer const& c )`.

However, in all of the examples in the boost documentation, it appears that this `tag_invoke` function must reside in the `Data` namespace, i.e. the same namespace as `Customer`.

I would like to know if it is possible to have something like the following:

```
namespace FileIO
{
void tag_invoke( const value_from_tag&, value& jv, Data::Customer const& c );
{
    jv = {
        { "id", c.id },
        { "name", c.name },
        { "late", c.late }
    };
}
}

namespace Network
{
void tag_invoke( const value_from_tag&, value& jv, Data::Customer const& c )
{
    jv = {
        { "id", c.id },
        { "late", c.late }
    };
}
}
```

In other words, have two different implementations of the value conversion, where the current namespace would determine which one gets used. I've not had any success getting it working, being met with various "no matching call to value_from_impl" errors.

In case it helps, my CMake setup is such that `Data`, `FileIO`, and `Network` are all separate targets, where both `FileIO` and `Network` are linked to/depend `Data`, but not to each other, and `Data` depends on no other libraries.

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag invoke is a more useful implementation of the old-fashioned ADL customization points. But it still heavily uses ADL. That means that associated namespaces are considered for overload resolution.

See https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1895r0.pdf for rationale.

You can declare unrelated overloads in other namespaces but,

- best case that namespace is not associated, and the overload is ignored
- worst case, that namespace is **also** associated, and the call becomes ambiguous.

> In case it helps, my CMake setup is such that Data, FileIO, and Network are all separate targets, where both FileIO and Network are linked to/depend Data, but not to each other, and Data depends on no other libraries.

That sounds like you have isolated source (*translation units*). You *can* define different customization points locally in those TUs. Make (doubly) sure they have internal linkage, so that you don't risk ODR violation. E.g.

```
namespace Data
{
     namespace { // anonymous namespace for file static (no external linkage)
        void tag_invoke( const value_from_tag&, value& jv, Customer const& c );
        {
          // ...
        };
     }
}
```

### Alternative

Alternatively, you can use tagged wrappers, a bit like manipulators:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aec23d41680e6bbc)**

```
#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <boost/json/src.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace json = boost::json;

template <typename T> struct UPPERCASE {
    T const& ref;
    UPPERCASE(T const& ref) : ref(ref) {}
};

namespace Data {
    struct Customer {
        int         id;
        std::string name;
        bool        late;

        friend void tag_invoke(json::value_from_tag,json::value&jv, Customer const& c) {
            jv = {{"id", c.id}, {"name", c.name}, {"late", c.late}};
        }
        friend void tag_invoke(json::value_from_tag, json::value& jv, UPPERCASE<Customer> const& c) {
            jv = {{"ID", c.ref.id}, {"NAME", c.ref.name}, {"LATE", c.ref.late}};
        }
    };
} // namespace Data

int main() {
    Data::Customer const c{1, "One", true};

    std::cout << json::value_from(c) << "\n";
    std::cout << json::value_from(UPPERCASE(c)) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
{"id":1,"name":"One","late":true}
{"ID":1,"NAME":"One","LATE":true}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. It has led me to some very interesting research, but unfortunately I have still not solved this issue in my project.

Using the first suggestion with anonymous namespaces, the overloads aren't being found (No matching function for call to 'value_from_impl'). Removing the anonymous namespaces solves this on an individual target level, but because I have a target which links to all three targets (Data, FileIO, Network), this obviously leads to a "duplicate symbols" linker error.

Comment: The second suggestion is interesting, but unfortunately is not the best solution because I have something like `std::vector<Customer> getCustomers();`, so when I declare a `void tag_invoke(json::value_from_tag, json::value& jv, UPPERCASE<Customer> const& c)` and try to use `json::value_from(UPPERCASE(getCustomers()));` boost can't figure out what to do with it.

Comment: Oh yeah. Anonymous namespaces break the ADL requirement, so you need to use the "manual" way of making synbols have file-static linkage (you guessed it, by marking them `static`). That was a brain-fart, sorry.

Comment: I feel like I got quite close to getting this working thanks to your help, but unfortunately it's just not quite there. In my 'Application' target (which links to all three other targets), I have instantiations of a FileIO::FileBuilder and a Network::JSONBuilder. Each of these only #includes their respective file with the `tag_invoke` functions in their .cpp, but when the code runs it doesn't work. 

I.e Application calls `FileBuilder::buildElement(foo);`, then `buildElement(T& obj)` calls `boost::value_from(obj)`, which finds the `tag_invoke` definition from the Network TU.

Comment: I've spent enough time on this now that I'll have to use a less elegant solution which avoids the whole tag dispatch/ADL structure, and just has explicit `CustomerToJSONValue` functions declared in each TU. I'll still accept your answer as it's definitely very close to helping me here, I think there are just some specialities in the structure of my current project that are preventing me from getting all the way there with it. Maybe if I have free time in a few weeks I'll try again, but for now I must move on to the next task. Thanks again for all of your help!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Yeah I tried to caution that trying to have different ADL-enabled overloads cannot work unless isolated in separate TUs. Did you mean you have tried the wrapper approach (Alternative)? Anyhow, there's value in simplicity, having dedicated conversion functions has my vote. The only thing that is reduced there is genericity, but it feels like genericity is _expressly_ not the goal here, so that's a good choice.

Comment: Yeah I did think that I had them isolated in separate TUs because the actual `tag_invoke` definitions were internally linked in their respective TUs, and then I was using these public classes (`FileIO::FileBuilder` and `Network::JSONBuilder`) in the `Application` layer to abstract the actual invocations of the value conversion. But oh well, somehow they leaked out of their isolation!

I tried the wrapper approach but the problem with it is when I have any container of Customer, which usually boost would automatically handle, but it can't manage `UPPERCASE(std::vector<Customer>)` for example